# Работа с Гугл Диском с помощью JAVA (получить файлы)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, google-drive, google-services

Добрый день !
Подскажите , пожалуйста 
У меня есть  папка на гугл диске с тхт файлами (общедоступная, как и фалы),
мне нужно в программе (java desctop) получить массив этих файлов напрямую с гугл диска для дальнейшего анализа.
Как это реализовывается и есть ли вообще варианты ?

Comment: у гугл-диска [есть Java-API](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client), и [документация](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

Comment: Знаю. Она мне не понятна. Если есть возможность - то можете пояснить моменты касательно моей задачи ?